# DataFrame object has no attribute 'sort_values'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
dataset = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv").fillna(" ")[:100]
dataset['Id']=0
dataset['i']=0
dataset['j']=0
#...
entries=dataset[dataset['Id']==0]
print type(entries)  # Prints <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
entries=entries.sort_values(['i','j','ColumnA','ColumnB'])
```

What might be the possible reason of the following error message **at the last line**?:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sort_values'
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Hello `sort_values` is [new in version 0.17.0](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), so check your version of pandas.
In the previous versions you should use `sort`.

```
entries=entries.sort(['i','j','ColumnA','ColumnB'])
```

Comment: How can I update `pandas` on Windows (preferably using `pip`)?

Comment: @KlausosKlausos `pip install -U pandas`?

Comment: @Anton Protopopov: Thanks. I did `pip install pandas --update`. Looks like it's updating `pandas`.

Comment: My advice on Windows is to use the [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) distribution since some dependencies of pandas could be tricky to update.

Comment: "--update" didnt work for me, but "--upgrade" did: "pip install pandas --upgrade"

Answer (score 3):

Check pandas version, In new versions uses `sort_values` in place of sort.