# DASK - AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sort_values'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dask

I am just trying to order a dask dataframe by a specific column.

**CODE 1** - If I call it it shows as indeed a ddf

`my_ddf`

**OUTPUT 1**

```
npartitions=1   
headers .....
```

**CODE 2**

`my_ddf.sort_values('id', ascending=False)`

**OUTPUT 2**

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-374-35ce4bd06557> in <module>
----> 1 my_ddf.sort_values('id', ascending=False) #.head(20)
      2 # df.sort_values(columns, ascending=True)

~/anaconda3/envs/rapids/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py in __getattr__(self, key)
   3619             return self[key]
   3620         else:
-> 3621             raise AttributeError("'DataFrame' object has no attribute %r" % key)
   3622 
   3623     def __dir__(self):

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sort_values'
```

**Tried Solutions**

- This is an example from the official dask documentation  `df.sort_values(columns, ascending=False).head(n)`
- pandas only - [DataFrame object has no attribute 'sort_values'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34499728/dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-sort-values)
- pandas only - ['DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sort'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44123874/dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-sort/44123892)
- DASK answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40378896/10270590

  - I don't want to set it in to index because I want to have only my current index values.
  - The following answer is a bit strange and I am not sure that it would work when I have more partition (currently I have 1 because if previous group by of the data) or how to not to have just a random big number "1000000000". Or how to make it Increasing from top to bottom in the dask dataframe `my_ddf.nlargest(1000000000, 'id').compute()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, sort across partitions is not implemented (yet?). If the dataset is small enough to fit in memory you can do `ddf = ddf.compute()` and then run sorting on the pandas dataframe.

Comment: Currently it is, but only because I am building out the pipeline with a smaller dataset. So it would be crucial to keep everything in DASK when I put x100 load on it it should still function.

Comment: I see, when I had a problem like that I had to incorporate additional logic that dask was not aware of, e.g. that certain values could only appear in certain partitions, so a full data shuffle was not needed. I ended up using `delayed` for that task.

Answer (score 2):

Dask indexes are not global anyway (by default)
If you want to retain the original within-partition index, you can do something like

```
df["old_index"] = df.reset_index()
df.set_index("colA")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the index as `id` and then do sorting through `map_partitions` like below:

```py
df = df.set_index("id")
df = df.map_partitions(lambda df: df.sort_values(["id"], ascending=False)).reset_index()
```